# parsing json list

Tags: python, json

I have this json object, am I am trying to parse to get the location from location_info there is an ID, and a written name.

```
{
"data": [
{
"id": 419,
"language": 1,
"size": "25.8 MB",
"title": "random title",
"location_info": "{\"168\": \"location one\"}",
"description": "Convallis aenean luctus dictum nullam tempus mi non, senectus dictumst sapien eget eros in inceptos nec, luctus suscipit libero fermentum litora hac.",
},
{
"id": 429,
"language": 1,
"size": "2.8 MB",
"title": "Lobortis est lacus nostra scelerisqu",
"location_info": "{\"169\": \"location two\"}",
"description": "Ipsum conubia consectetur magna ad ullamcorper habitant",
},
{
"id": 412,
"language": 1,
"size": "5.8 MB",
"title": "proin convallis lobortis ligula purus ",
"location_info": "{\"169\": \"location two\", \"168\": \"location one\"}",
"description": "purus ultrices sed bibendum placerat non semper phasellus per vehicula leo id feugiat faucibus.",
},
],
"total": 3,
"total_found": 10
}
```

Here is my little test code, I am using

```
with open('json1.json') as f:
  jsonResponse = json.load(f, "UTF-8")

  jsonData = jsonResponse["data"]
  for item in jsonData:
    print ("%s  Len %s") % (item.get('location_info'), len(item.get('location_info')))


{u'168': u'location one'}  Len 1
{u'169': u'location two'}  Len 1
{u'169': u'location two', u'168': u'location one'}  Len 2
```

I can get the length of the list, being 1 or 2,  or the whole string. but I can't get just the location name back, nor what the ID number is.

If I try to get just the first part of the string as a list

```
print (item.get('location_info')[0])
```

I just get keyerror: 0 back

What I would like, is to be able to get the location ID, and name, in a way that I can easily deal with.  and yes there can be multiple locations.

Comment: `location_info` isn’t a list here, it’s a dict (with key <some id> and value <name>). Look for dict methods to deal with it. Better would be if you could change the JSON to have id and name be different keys in `location_info`

Comment: the problem is, its not my api giving me data like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.get('location_info')` is a dict here,

You have to use the ID("168" or "169") instead of index(0 or 1).

to show `location_info` in every `data`, you can do:

```
for item in jsonData:
    # for ID in item['location_info'] returns every `key` in location_info
    for ID in item['location_info']:
        print(ID, item['location_info'][ID])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `location_info` field in your json is actually an embedded json string:

```
"location_info": "{\"168\": \"location one\"}",  # <- that's a string
```

The json parser will not recursively parse things like this. You need to parse it before you can use it:

```
for item in jsonData:
    location = json.loads(item.get('location_info1', '{}'))
    print(location.keys()) # NOW location is a dictionary
```

Prints:

```
dict_keys(['168'])
dict_keys(['169'])
dict_keys(['169', '168'])
```